# Accessing external iframe content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a page with an iframe A whose src attribute is a url that iteself contains an iframe B A. I want to access the src of this embedded iframe B. Is this possible at all? It seems browser security won't let this happen since the embedded iframe B comes from outside the domain of my iframe A.

Comment: What do you mean by "src", the `src` attribute or the HTML source code?

Comment: Do you own the code for the contents in that other frame?

Comment: No, I don't own the code for the other frame.

Comment: I tried to load the remote page into a hidden iframe. From there, I tried using jquery to extract the src of the hidden iframe. But, I can't retrieve the src of the embedded iframe. I hope that was clear, if not maybe this is clearer: before loading the remote page my page has this iframe <iframe id="myid" src="somepage.php"></iframe>. After loading somepage.php, I have this: <iframe id="myid" src="somepage.php"><iframe src="another_page.php"></iframe></iframe>. I want to extract "another_page.php" and load it as the source of <iframe id="myid">

Answer (score 2):

You are correct; this is completely impossible.

Otherwise, I could write a page that loads Gmail in a hidden `<iframe>` and read your email.

Comment: I liked your answer. Simple and descriptive. It made me think: if you don't pass the cookies to the loaded page you won't be logged (to Gmail or whatever). So, could there be any way of "safe-loading" an external page into an iframe (without cookies) so you can access its contents via JavaScript without the risk of impersonating?

Comment: @FerranMaylinch: No, because cookies aren't the only risk.  What about corporate internal apps that are whitelisted by IP address. (which is a bad idea, but that's beside the point.)

Comment: AFAIK I can't access third party pages via CORS if they haven't allowed access.

Comment: Correct; that's why it doesn't break the security of the web.

Answer (score 1):

yea the browser security prevents you

but theres other ways of getting crossdomain content
you can use http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/

there some plugins for jquery to if thats you cup

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 actually has a security model for this. Check out PostMessage in HTML5 compliant browsers. There is a demo here: http://html5demos.com/postmessage2

If not, jQuery has a nice plugin that supports this, and even has a fallback to using the anchor tag to communicate if running in a browser that does not support PostMessage properly: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-postmessage-plugin/

Good luck!

:)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot for the reason you guessed at.  However, if you have control over the contents of that other domain's frame, there are ways you can add cross-domain frame communication.